# Getting URISyntaxException in while calling SOAP web service

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client

I'm consuming a SOAP web service. When the service is called, I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 66:
```

I tried:

```
encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(encodedUrl, "UTF-8");
```

and I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.createConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit.setupConnection(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:478)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
```

Comment: can you provide the URL value?

Comment: this is the url http://10.21.9.38:9408/corporateservices/maintainaccountprofile/v2

Comment: it should have a http:// or https:// before it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URL value is complete, meaning it should contain a protocal, a host, a port(host and port are optional based on the protocal but for http and https they are mandatory), and the rest of the url